# Изменение толщины обводки svg треугольника только внутрь относительно осевой линии stroke

Tags: вёрстка, svg, математика, анимация, геометрия

Есть **равносторонний треугольник** с произвольными координатами.

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
<polygon fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke="red" points="200 35.45517328095667,10 364.54482671904333,390 364.54482671904333"></polygon>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6sybjthL/1/

Из-за особенностей svg, при изменении толщины обводки (stroke-width) идёт расширение одновременно и внутрь, и наружу. На сколько мне известно, для svg версии 1.1 нет какого-то свойства, которое это изменяет, поможет только геометрия и математика.

Отсюда 2 вопроса:

1. Какую формулу применять для пересчёта координат треугольника при изменении толщины обводки на произвольное значение, чтобы треугольник **оставался равносторонним** и **не расширялся визуально наружу** (то есть происходит заполнение фона треугольника)?.
2. Как посчитать максимальный размер обводки, при которой треугольник будет полностью заполнен за счёт такой обводки только внутрь?

**UPD**

Ниже пример моих попыток пересчитать координаты для нового значения stroke-width=40. (цель сделать так, чтобы зеленый треугольник не выходил за красный)

https://jsfiddle.net/xqv3ms8b/9/

Comment: @MaximLensky viewBox менять нельзя.

Comment: Помимо треугольника, в svg куча других объектов может быть. Изменение viewBox затрагивает их, поэтому viewBox менять нельзя. Вопрос конкретно про треугольник и stroke-width. Css свойства не подойдут, это необходимо сделать средствами svg. Это можно сделать, я просто не могу понять какую формулу взять за основу, если в начале есть координаты x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3 и stroke-width. Затем stroke-width меняется на произвольное значение и нужно пересчитать все координаты так, чтобы граничные точки треугольника не поменялись (визуально треугольник остался на месте), но обводка стала толще.

Comment: Это можно сделать. Естественно это будет реализовано на javascript. Для понимания тогда напишу как это будет работать, есть ползунок - его крутишь, меняется толщина обводки. И пересчитываются координаты. Но чтобы их пересчитать надо понять формулу. Аналогичная задача для круга/прямоугольника решается значительно проще, там просто добавляется корректировка позиций/диаметра на половину текущей толщины обводки и идёт расширение только ВНУТРЬ. С треугольником же, как я понимаю, геометрия посложнее.

Comment: Я специально свёл задачу к одному треугольнику для простоты понимания. Количество других элементов внутри svg динамическое, их может быть много, они могут быть разного размера, разные фигуры, могут быть другие svg внутри. Это не играет роли. Задача только про треугольник. Есть координаты треугольника и толщина обводки. Обводка меняется и у каждой вершины должны быть новые координаты. Я бьюсь разными способами пытаюсь их пересчитать, но с геометрией видимо у меня проблемы.

Comment: Для понимания вот как это делается с кругом. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477645/how-to-draw-stroke-inside-a-circle Почти аналогично с прямоугольником/квадратом, простая формула и дальше можно пересчитывать для любого размера. С треугольником сложнее.

Comment: Общая схема может быть такая: 1) построить уравнение стороны по вершинам 2) построить уравнение нормали к стороне в обеих вершинах 3) сдвинуть вершины вдоль нормалей на половину толщины границы 3) получить новое уравнение стороны 4) повторить для всех трех сторон 5)  по новым уравнениям сторон найти новые вершины как точки пересечения. Собственно, все. Как решать каждый отдельный пункт - легко находится в гугл: уравнение прямой по двум точкам ,уравнение нормали к прямой в точке, нахождение точки пересечения прямых.

Comment: Вероятно, схема довольно громоздкая, но зато она должна сработать, если все проделать аккуратно :)

Comment: Звучит сложно. Честно говоря, уже на втором пункте у меня проблемы и непонимание чего, как и куда использовать. 1 я сделал вроде бы. −329.08965343808666x−190y+72554.4136109991=0;
0x+380y−138527.03415323648=0;
−329.08965343808666x+190y+59081.44776423556=0; Я отдам всю текущую, хоть и небольшую, репутацию тому, кто поможет разобраться с этой задачей и научит пересчитывать координаты треугольника.

Comment: Честно - мне просто лень расписывать это полноценным ответом. Поэтому - по второму пункту схемы - [вот](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/9880453)  ой.. у меня там с нумерацией косяк... (3-1) сдвинуть вершину - теорема Пифагора. Вам нужно найти точку, лежащую на нормали на расстоянии половины толщины обводки от исходной вершины. Когда все посчитаете и получите новые уравнения сторон - вершины ищутся как пересечение сторон, то есть как решение системы двух линейных уравнений, описывающих стороны. Три пары сторон - три вершины.

Comment: Эх, мои знания в геометрии слабоваты. Но спасибо за наводку. Я попытаюсь, конечно, но сомневаюсь, что я всё равно пойму сам как это всё выполнить и не запутаюсь. Придется ждать помощи дальше или сутки, когда можно будет назначить вознаграждение за вопрос.

Comment: @Floyat значит я поторопился, так хотелось поделиться с вами интересной идей

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Решение SVG + Mask

Идея такая:

Чтобы обрезать внешнюю половину строки и не мешать росту внутренней половине строки при увеличении `stroke-width`, воспользуемся mask SVG

Фигура (любая) добавляется в mask в секции `defs`
У `path` этой фигуры назначаются стили `fill="white"` и `stroke="white"` Это сделает  маску, которая будет показывать изначально шаблон исходной фигуры с постоянной шириной строки.
Излишки **внешней половины** строки, при увеличении `stroke-width`   будут обрезаться вторым элементом маски  `<rect>`
Внутренняя половина строки будет увеличиваться без ограничений.

**mask**

```
<defs>
<mask id="msk">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
<polygon  fill="white" stroke-width="8" stroke="black" points="200 35.5 10 364.5 390 364.5"></polygon>
</mask> 
</defs>
```

Вторую фигуру, у которой будем изменять `stroke-width` с точно таким же path, как и фигура в `mask`  помещаем ниже в теле фигуры и применяем к ней маску `mask="url(#msk)"`  Внешняя часть строки будет обрезана маской, а внутренняя часть будет показана без обрезки, то есть будет увеличиваться при увеличении `stroke-width`

- Ниже в программе добавлен круг с постоянными атрибутами, который
  описывает исходную фигуру, показывая тем самым, что габаритные
  размеры фигуры остаются без изменений при увеличении `stroke-width`
- JS добавлен только, для демонстрации работы mask по обрезке внешней
  стороны `stroke-width`

```js
function changeStroke() {
var sw = document.getElementById("poly"); 
   itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{sw.setAttribute("stroke-width",itr.value)});
    var x = document.getElementById("itr").value;
    
    document.getElementById("infoSW").innerHTML = "stroke-width: " + x +"px";
}
```

```html
<div>
 <input id="itr" type="range" min="4" value="4" max="150"  oninput="changeStroke()"/>

</div>
<div><text id="infoSW">stroke-width:4px </text></div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 500">
<defs>
<mask id="msk">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
<polygon  fill="white" stroke-width="8" stroke="white" points="200 35.5 10 364.5 390 364.5"></polygon>
</mask> 

</defs> 

    <polygon id="poly" mask="url(#msk)" fill="yellowgreen" stroke-width="4" stroke="red" points="200 35.5 10 364.5 390 364.5"></polygon>
      <circle cx="200" cy="252" r="4" fill="black" stroke="black" />
    <circle cx="200" cy="252" r="224" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="4" />
</svg>
```

**Чтобы показать, что данная техника обрезки внешней части строки универсальна, добавлю более сложный элемент**

```js
function changeStroke() {
var sw = document.getElementById("poly"); 
     itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{sw.setAttribute("stroke-width",itr.value)});
    var x = document.getElementById("itr").value;
    
    document.getElementById("infoSW").innerHTML = "stroke-width: " + x +"px";
}
```

```html
<div>
 <input id="itr" type="range" min="4" value="4" max="20"  oninput="changeStroke()"/>
</div>
<div><text id="infoSW">stroke-width:4px </text></div>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="500" height="400" viewBox="40 200 100 125">
<defs>
<mask id="msk">
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />
<path fill="white" stroke-width="4" stroke="white" d="m32.5 272c-16.3-5.6-11.4-33.8 0-31.4 0-10.6 13.4-18.7 22.8-9.4 0 0 2.4-13.4 21.1-13.4 19.1 0.1 22.6 21.2 22.6 21.2 15.8-1.3 18.6 24.6 4.8 32.6z"
</mask> 

</defs> 
    <path id="poly" mask="url(#msk)" fill="white" stroke="skyblue" stroke-width="4" stroke-linecap="round"  stroke-linejoin="round" d="m32.5 272c-16.3-5.6-11.4-33.8 0-31.4 0-10.6 13.4-18.7 22.8-9.4 0 0 2.4-13.4 21.1-13.4 19.1 0.1 22.6 21.2 22.6 21.2 15.8-1.3 18.6 24.6 4.8 32.6z"
</svg>
```

Comment: Браво! Это великолепное решение. Как я понял, если мне не нужна заливка, то соответственно не требуется и rect элемент в маске и stroke у полигона в маске. Модифицировал ваш пример https://jsfiddle.net/wv5j9f0q/1/ Не очень понимаю как это работает, но вижу, что работает. Единственное, что осталось понять, но не уверен реально ли это вообще - определить максимальное значение stroke-width, при котором фон полигона будет полностью заполнен. В примере я подобрал это значение на глаз как 219, но не могу понять как это обосновать математически и как найти заранее.

Comment: @Floyat вот почитайте мою [статью про маски](http://svg-art.ru/?p=1862). Старался доходчиво, на картинках объяснить, как это всё работает. Задайте новый вопрос по своей модификации кода, что вам не понятно, как работает Постараюсь, если смогу :) оперативно ответить

Answer (score 2):

***Есть ещё один способ избежать дополнительного увеличения габаритных размеров фигуры за счет прироста внешней половины толщины строки, при масштабировании `scale(X,Y)`***

В SVG есть атрибут строки [vector-effect1="non-scaling-stroke"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/vector-effect)

Этот атрибут предотвращает увеличение ширины строки при увеличении или уменьшении элемента SVG.

Другими словами, как не изменяй размеры фигуры с помощью `scale()` или `viewBox`, строка не изменит свою ширину.

**#1. Пример без `vector-effect1="non-scaling-stroke"`**

При увеличении размеров фигуры, увеличивается толщина stroke

*Анимация начнется после клика по холсту:*

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="250" height="250" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 250 250" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid" >
    <rect x="10" y="10 "width="50" height="50" rx="10" fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="4">
     <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       type="scale"
       values="1;1.5;2;2.5;3;3.5;4"
       calcMode="discrete"
       begin="svg1.click"
       dur="6s"
       repeatCount="1"
       fill="freeze"
      </rect>      
      </svg>
```

**#2. Пример с использованием vector-effect1="non-scaling-stroke"**

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="250" height="250" version="1.1"
viewBox="0 0 250 250" 
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid" >
    <rect x="10" y="10 "width="50" height="50" rx="10" fill="none" stroke="crimson" stroke-width="4" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" >
     <animateTransform
       attributeName="transform"
       type="scale"
       values="1;1.5;2;2.5;3;3.5;4"
       calcMode="discrete"
       begin="svg1.click"
       dur="6s"
       repeatCount="1"
       fill="freeze" />
      </rect>      
 </svg>
```

**Обратите внимание**, что фигура заняла в финальном положении несколько меньшее место по сравнению с первым примером, за счет того, что не увеличилась толщина строки